# Lookup of users from list using ID as filter in Workflow - Error Occured

Tags: workflow, office-365

So I have a workflow for a Purchase Order system. But when it runs, at a certain point, it pulls some approver display names from a list (finance admins) - using a predetermined number as the ID field to filter, thus finding the correct values.

For some reason I'm getting `Error occurred` (non-specific of course, I've narrowed it down to this stage by trial and error).

This seems to be the problem:
https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/0/AAAfz01qLh367Gd2MLfuNABhvUKsJyZ_1_lrMJpZ3ZrfZg/12/57992759/png/2048x1536/3/1387209600/0/2/Screenshot%202013-12-16%2014.30.30.png/nar0WcQGDL1cU5pJZTDsV7mi2IUw9cv7fA0JABiKLr8

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the workflow? Have you checked the ULS logs when you get the error?

Comment: @Mike Can't check the ULS logs as far as I'm aware.. should have mentioned this is on Office 365. This is the section of workflow where the problem originates. The setting of permissions is what goes wrong, presumably from the list lookup as mentioned above. https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/0/AAAdit4PAvdHpnytirLTHfzbtkKHRltW35-_6qo29jIiNQ/12/57992759/png/2048x1536/3/1387278000/0/2/Screenshot%202013-12-17%2009.46.29.png/CSAwCA6i5MxyI-N0LWOspItkHai55j8D-GaC1ZqvXrw